# Is there a policy on dodgy questions?

Tags: discussion

I don't want to get personal, so no links to example questions, but sometimes I feel uncomfortable answering some questions like:

- How do I hack my employers network?
- How do I spam my teacher?

(not actual questions, but similar enough for everyone to get the point)

These questions are not spam, nor hate speech, off-topic, unclear, ...

And my question is: "How should we proceed with questions like this?"

Comment: hmm, I haven't noticed anything that obvious.. but it is a good question.

Comment: You know I think that seems like a reasonable request under certain circumstances. It is hard to discuss if we don't have some common examples, but I think that is hardly "how do I spam my teacher". Still worth discussing however.

Comment: :D That's why I used the examples I gave and didn't include the ones I found (slightly) uncomfortable: I just want to know how to proceed, and I'm also *very* good at reading between the lines: I once had to cross the t's and dot the i's before (some?) of the moderators saw what I saw: product placement (thus spam)

Comment: We have had a few "Help me hack this blah" questions - they all got downvoted and closed off-topic pretty quickly. I don't remember seeing any recently, though.

Comment: Last I checked those were valid on Internet Security in SE.  Although, "help me hack this guy" will not gain you anything positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question: How do I use aircrack-ng is valid (but asked before so can be duped) since the aircrack-ng package is in the repos. And it can be used to do dodgy things.

1 thing in favor of keeping them open:

Those employees and that teacher can use that same question to find countermeasures.

Comment: What about "Why can't `aircrack-ng` crack my neighbour's WiFi?"

Comment: Because they have a good security :+ And if it was possible to crack would it not better for everyone to know (INCLUDING the neighbours). There are people using aircrack that do not come here (I even doubt you should show your face on AU when asking about aircrack but that's just me problably :X )